# Does primary/allied clan settings affect how much experience is gained?

Tags: monster-train

If I wanted to unlock the clans as fast as possible, does it matter if I set them as the primary clan or secondary clan?  Do they earn experience at the same rate?

Comment: Allied clan seems to be generally gaining less experience; but this what I felt while playing I have no evidence (and did not particularly pay attention to it...) This might also be based on card usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. After you win or lose a run, your **primary** clan will gain your run's score as experience, while your **secondary** clan will gain 50% of your score as experience. So if you gained 40,000 points the primary clan gains 40,000 XP, while your secondary gains 20,000.

I'm not sure if there's an additional cap at the end of each level (like this game's inspiration slay the spire has), I think it's maybe possible to gain more than one level from a single high-scoring run, would have to verify this.

Comment: I can confirm that it is possible to gain multiple levels at once.